# How to upload a unity game which is more than 50 mb to google playstore?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

Hi I have a unity game which is around 150mb. I need to upload it to google playstore. Any one knows any work around for this?

Comment: You can upload a version without the heavy resources then download them from within the game itself.

Comment: look into Unity Asset Server as well to offload some resource heavy stuff.

Comment: Also to save some space you can Strip ByteCode or use micro mscorlib. But that only does so much, 100 MB is a lot of data to offload.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you compile your game you can use "Split Application Binary" in the android player settings -> publishing settings. This **automatically** splits up your build in a way that can be submitted to the store by creating an .APK and an .OBB file.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-OBBsupport.html

From the docs:

"This mechanism is only necessary when publishing to the Google Play Store, if the application is larger than 50 MB."

Comment: That's basically the same as my answer, just automated.

Comment: Yes but my solution is part of the Unity3D Engine, your answer did not mention the Unity Engine at all. As a Unity developer it is highly discouraged to follow your directions because they dont always apply to how Unity works. Unity has its own ways to do things, if they have a solution built in, best practice is to follow their solution. Its convention over configuration.

Comment: I've added this to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a work around. Your must be below 50 Megabytes. 
You have to use so called expansion files, which can be up to 2 Gigabytes and should contain all your graphics / video / storage expensive stuff.

Please take a look at the Android documentary: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

**Edit:** If you're developing a Unity game, you should follow the way by [MichaelTaylor3D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1603933/michaeltaylor3d).

Comment: well, i think that is the workaround he was looking for... :)

Comment: Isn't a workaround something which works around set limits? Nevertheless, it's the solution for the issue he has. ;)

Comment: Yes, it's posted there. The Android documentation explain it pretty well.

Comment: There is a work around for a Unity Build, its in player settings