# Uploading Andengine Apk [More than 50MB]

Tags: android, andengine

> Hi All,
>
> I hv developer andengine game which is 70 Mb and i wanna upload that in google play , there is option in unity game to use "Split Application Binary" [Ref Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958272/how-to-upload-a-unity-game-which-is-more-than-50-mb-to-google-playstore) , Is that possible with Andengine game also?